# Qt QSerialport unpluged device not close

Tags: c++, linux, qt, serial-port, usb

`QSerialPort` cant close an unplugged device in  rasbian system. any method close and reconnect the port . This code is working but I quickly unplug and plugin it is not working . ı think serial doesnt break while plug is connected :

```
    serial->close();
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    serial->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    if(serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        qDebug() << "Hata yok";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "Hata var";
    }
```

Comment: Offer your code as text not picture

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

While unplugging It maybe emit `error` ***`SIGNAL`***, so connect `error` ***`SIGNAL`*** to a ***`SLOT`*** to handle it like bellow :

```
QObject::connect(serial, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this,
                 SLOT(handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));

void Widget::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{
    if (error == QSerialPort::ResourceError)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Critical Error"), serial->errorString());
        serial->close();
    }
}
```